# Отсутствие запятой перед «исходя из»

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, деепричастия

Поясните, пожалуйста, почему отсутствует запятая перед "исходя из"?

*Таблица составлена исходя из полученных сведений.*

Answer (score 3):

Одиночное деепричастие или деепричастный оборот не обособляется, если деепричастие утратило глагольное значение.

Оборот со словами ***исходя из*** (= на основании) в большинстве случаев не входит в деепричастную конструкцию и не обособляется:
*Статистические показатели выводятся **исходя из многих данных*** (слово *исходя* можно опустить); *Таблица составлена **исходя из полученных сведений**; Годовая потребность рассчитывается **исходя из потребностей** на каждый квартал.*

[Деепричастные конструкции](http://old-rozental.ru/punctum_uk.php?pid=136) (примечание, п. 5)

**Таблица составлена** [исходя] **из полученных сведений** (именно этот пример есть в правиле Д. Э. Розенталя).

Answer (score 1):

Деепричастный оборот не обособляется, если оборот (обычно со значением обстоятельства образа действия) тесно связан по содержанию со сказуемым и образует смысловой центр высказывания:

*Она сидела чуть откинув голову (Марк.) — указывается не просто, что она сидела, а что сидела с откинутой головой; Жили Артамоновы ни с кем не знакомясь (М.Г.) — важно не то, что жили, а что жили без всяких знакомств.*

**Ваш оборот «*составлена исходя из*» — то же, что и «*составлена на основании*».**